# Why isn't Array.newInstance(Class<?>, int) generic?

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I mean, is there any good reason for that? The [method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance(java.lang.Class,%20int))'s got the following signature:

```
public static Object newInstance(Class<?> componentType,
                 int length)
                          throws NegativeArraySizeException
```

In my opinion, it would be much more convinient to declare the method as follows:

```
public static <T> T[] newInstance(Class<T> componentType, int length) 
                                          throws NegativeArraySizeException
```

That way, when creating an aray of generic type it would not be neccesary to perform additional casting, e.g.

```
public class Gen<T>{
    private T[] a;

    public static <T> Gen<T> createByClass(Class<T> clazz){
        a = clazz.cast(Array.newIntance(clazz.getComponentType(), 8); //we have to invoke 
                                                                      //clazz.cast here.
    }
}
```

Was there any good reason to declare the return value type as `Object`? To me it seems very incovinient.

Comment: Firstly, I suspect it predates generics. Secondly, I'm not sure what would happen for `int.class` etc.

Comment: @JonSkeet what do you mean when mentioning `int.class`? I thought that requesting class objects of primitives always returns their reference wrapper class object...

Comment: No, definitely not - if you call `Array.newInstance(int.class, 5)` you'll get an `int[]` back, not an `Integer[]`.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, now I see this. I didn't take arrays of primitives into consideration. Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `Array.newInstance(Class<?> componentType, int length)` to create

- Arrays of **Objects**: `Integer[] a = (Integer[])Array.newInstance(Integer.class, 5);`
- Arrays of **primitives**: `int[] b = (int[])Array.newInstance(int.class, 5);`
- Arrays of **Arrays**: `int[][] c = (int[][])Array.newInstance(b.getClass(), 5);`

The second example illustrates why this method cannot just return a generic array of objects, as **arrays of primitves aren't array of objects** (arrays of arrays, on the other hand, are).

Using this helper method...

```
private static <T> T[] newArray(Class<?> type, int len){
    return (T[])Array.newInstance(type, len);
}
```

...with `int[] b = newArray(int.class, 5);` will result in a compilation error:

> Incompatible types, required int[], but found T[]

...and with `int[] b = (int[])newArray(int.class, 5);` will result in a compilation error:

> cannot cast Object[] to int[]